# does media queries not work in html emails?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am using action mailer to send this email template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />

        <style>

        @media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */
         img{

                    width: 100%;

            }

        }
        @media (min-width:480px)  { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */

             img{

                    width: 100%;

            }
        }
        @media (min-width:600px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ 
             img{

                    width: 100%;

            }

        }
        @media (min-width:801px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ 

            img{

                    width: 50%;
                }

        }
        @media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 

            img{

                    width: 50%;
                }

        }
        @media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 

            img{

                    width: 50%;
                }


        }





        </style>

  </head>
  <body>

<%= image_tag(attachments['banner.png'].url) %>

<p> Thanks for purchasing with us! </p>

<hr>


</body>
</html>
```

The effect of this is in mobile screen the width is set mysteriously to 960px as shown below. According to the media query rules i have set it to be 100% which should be 100% of the parent div container which should fit the image nicely in the mobile view but in mobile view it sets the width to 960px so only partial image is displayed. How can i make it width: 100% instead of width: 960px on mobile screens? Thanks!

[image]

**Update:**

To test please use the following code. You can use the following template for action-mailer email. I am using rails and action-mailer. Using action-mailer i send the following html email. After the email is received please view it in mobile and you will see that the image stretches far beyond the screen width. In chrome you can view it in mobile mode and rightclick on the image to inspect it and you will see the max-width set to 960px.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />

        <style>

        @media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */
         img{

                    width: 100% !important;

            }

        }
        @media (min-width:480px)  { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */

             img{

                    width: 100% !important;

            }
        }
        @media (min-width:600px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ 
             img{

                    width: 100% !important;

            }

        }
        @media (min-width:801px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ 

            img{

                    width: 50% !important;
                }

        }
        @media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 

            img{

                    width: 50% !important;
                }

        }
        @media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 

            img{

                    width: 50% !important;
                }


        }





        </style>

  </head>
  <body>

<%= image_tag('http://via.placeholder.com/5548x985') %>

<p> Thanks for purchasing with us! </p>

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope this link will help you: https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email   check scheme at the bottom

Comment: I would say that if you want to do a different layout for emails you/your customer/your company are going about email promotion the wrong way. Inline styles is the way you do email. You can sign up at mailchimp and look how they do. You are wasting time with this IMO.

Answer (score -2):

Media queries is supported in email templates. You need to set the viewport as below inside the head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: sorry even after adding the meta tag the max-width: 960px is still there that is preventing resize.

Comment: also use html4 doctype

Comment: Use this <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Media queries have very poor support. Setting the viewport tag will not help. https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/

Comment: @ShahilM Do you have any evidence to support your answer?

Comment: @Turnip Thanks that was helpful. Do you know any alternative to using media queries to solve this problem? i know sendgrid has responsive images when we use their templates but at this point i donot want to use external email service providers. i am using rails and actionmailer. thanks for help!

Comment: @kofhearts Sorry, it's been a long time since I've coded emails by hand. Most of my clients use MailChimp these days.